# Can't assign data table value into string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys a have a really simple data table, which is imported via excel by this:

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "A:B]";
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dt);
```

I don't use any header, so the names of columns are default - F1 and F2. The thing is, that I couldn't assign any value from the second column to the variable. But the values from the first one could be assigned properly.

```
string firstColumn = dt.Rows[1]["F1"] as string;
string secondColumn = dt.Rows[1]["F2"] as string;
```

I attached a screen, where you can see, what is in data table. In firstColumn is stored "ABC" which is alright, but the secondColumn value is null. It should be easy, but something is wrong here and I have no idea what. Can you help me?

[image: Attached image]

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `dt.Rows[1]["F2"]`? What does `dt.Rows[1]["F2"].GetType().FullName` return?

Comment: its probably an int - dont ````as string````

Comment: It returns double, so that's the problem. Thanks Marc. I just thought that if it's imported by excel and dt is created automatically, the all cells would be the same type - string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Explicitly cast it to `Int32` instead of string like below:

```
int secondColumn = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[1]["F2"]);
```

Your screen shot shows it as integer value. So if you cast it to integer, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
dt.Rows[1]["F1"]
```

This seems contradictory.

- `dt.Rows[1]` retrieves the **second** row of the document
- `"F1"` can be found on the **first** row of the document.

**However,** you claim that the first assignation works. It seems weird to me (Excel does not use 0-based indexing), but I'll assume that you know what you're talking about.

That does mean that the other assignation does not make sense.

```
dt.Rows[1]["F2"]
```

If you claim that `dt.Rows[1]["F1"]` is retrieved, then I would expect field **F2** to be found on `dt.Rows[2]`, not `dt.Rows[1]`.

---

Regardless of whether the issue occurs in the first or second line of code, I think that the field you're trying to retrieve simply doesn't exist in the specific row you're addressing.